# Which Data Mining Method?

Tags: data-mining, confusion-matrix

I have millions of confusion matrices. Which data mining method I should use to summarize them or find the relationship between these matrices?
I would be thankful if you can give me a hint that can be helpful for me.

Comment: Why millions of confusion matrices? What task are you performing?

Answer (score 0):

The method depends on the kind of relationship you intend to find.

Your key question should be how to measure similarity of these matrixes.

Answer (score 0):

A [Confusion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix) is mostly used to give a numeric values on performance of a Classification model. It's both strange and interesting that you have millions of them!!! (It would be helpful if you add some explanation that from where did you end up having millions of confusion matrices!)

If your confusion matrices are coming from such procedure, then you might need to work on the rates they give (such as 'accuracy', 'precision', 'specificity', 'recall', etc) as your new features. And then, based on the those features, you may directly apply another classification/clustering model to achieve your ultimate goal, or start with some [feature selection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_selection) (using descriptive statistics for instance: Min, Max, Mean, Median, Var) or [feature extraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_extraction) to reduce the complexity (dimensionality) of your space.